# Tag holdemanager should be renamed

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

We got a tag called `holdemanager` but this is wrong. It is called `holdemmanager` - so we should rename this tag. I would suggest name `holdem-manager` for this tracking software.

Or is there a place where I can suggest to rename a tag?

Actually most people use holdem-manager 2 - so there should be a tag `holdem-manager-2` as well and a synonym `hm2`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right place for tag discussions. Done.

Since there are only three questions tagged [holdem-manager](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/holdem-manager), I suspect creating a new tag to differentiate between versions and a synonym is overkill at this point.